# Spring: How to make some non-Async methods in a Component

Tags: java, spring, asynchronous

I've searched several times for an answer to this to no avail.

I want a Spring component with some @Async methods and some that are not.  Like this:

```
@Component
public class MyComp {
  @Autowired private OtherComp delegate;
  @Async
  void doAsyncAction() { delegate.doAction(); }
  // non-Async
  Object getData() { return delegate.getSomeData(); }
}
```

Unfortunately, when the getData method is called the delegate is null.
I can create a work-around that uses a CompleteableFuture to return the datum Object but that's overhead that isn't necessary.

```
@Component
public class MyComp {
  @Autowired private OtherComp delegate;
  @Async
  void doAsyncAction() { delegate.doAction(); }
  @Async
  CompleteableFuture<Object> getData() { return CompleteableFuture.completedFuture(delegate.getSomeData()); }
}
```

Does anyone know of a better work-around?

Thanks,
Bryan

Comment: Are you sure that the `delegate` was injected before `getData` is called? For me it seems that your issue has nothing to do with asynchrony. But, if `delegate.getSomeData()` is async as well, then probably you have to use `CompleteableFuture`.

Comment: I tried your example and I'm facing no issue. I agree with @ErvinSzilagyi may your `delegate.getSomeData()` be async for any reason? In this case if you don't use `CompleteableFuture` you'll get null

Comment: Make the methods `public` instead of package protected. Using `@Async` requires a proxy, however default methods aren't intercepted. Only `public` and `protected` methods.

Comment: Thanks for the responses, everyone.  The `getSomeData` method is not async; neither is the `doAction` method.  I am wrapping the delegate like this in order to make these methods (from a third-party library) asynchronous. I know that the `delegate` is autowired *before* the `getData` method is called.  And, in my brevity I left out `public` from these methods; sorry.